# Sitecore Workbox

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-workflow

I am trying to setup some RSS feeds for our editors, so they can see items in certain workflows. We have three workflows; draft, awaiting approval and approved. However, in workbox we can only see awaiting approval and approved.

What would be the reason for this? I have the correct workflow ticked 'standard workflow'.

This is Sitecore 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood, you have a workflow called `Standard Workflow` and it has 3 states: "Draft", "Awaiting Approval" and "Approved". And in your workbox, you can only see "Awaiting Approval" and "Approved" states.

Workbox only shows states for which user can execute any command. So e.g. if there is `Approve` command in `Awaiting Approval` state and your user has appropriate access rights which allows you to execute that command, then you will see `Awaiting Approval` state in your workbox. If user cannot execute ANY command in particular state, this state is hidden from the workbox.

Comment: Exactly, Ah that will explain it! once it is in approved state the user cannot action anything. I thought like you, but the user is insisting that they used to have that RSS feed of approved pages. I'm guessing it is a mistake on their behalf. Thanks for taking the time to answer my query.

Comment: It is possible that there is an option to create a link with Approved items RSS feed using same mechanism which is used in the Workbox. Never tried it though.

Comment: Ah really? do you have any reference to that?

Comment: As I wrote above, I'd never tried it. You should check the url structure of the RSS link - maybe there is state id hardcoded or something?

Comment: Brilliant, I'll dig around - thanks Marek, much appreciated

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the RSS feeds in the work box are user-specific. The URL to the feed contains a security token that silently logs the user in to get only the items they have permission to see (the links in the feed will also be user specific). That said, you could have a user with the appropriate permissions login to get that feed. All that said, you shouldn't share the RSS feed URL's across users.